# I can not do a search with words in brackets in php

Tags: php, arrays, search, preg-match

I created a function to check if there are some words in an array. I want to do the search for words within square brackets "[ ]" .
Example: [dar], [como], [amar] ...

For that, I am using the preg_match () function to check for any of the words in the array. However, the function is accepting a verification of words without the brackets .

Example : The word "darkgreen" is accepted because it has "dar" at first, but I just want to accept the word "[dar]"

This is my code and sample text where do the verification:

My code:

```
private function checkTerms($post){
    $out= array();

    foreach ($this->terms as $term) {
        $er = "[".$term."]";
        if(preg_match($er,$post)){
            $out[] = $term;
        }
    }

    return $out;
}
```

Array example:

```
<dl>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">como</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[como]</font>  &lt;rel&gt; &lt;ks&gt; <font color="blue"><b>ADV</b> </font> <font color="darkgreen">@ADVL&gt;</font> <font color="darkgreen"><b>@#FS-ADVL</font></b> <font color="darkgreen"><b>@#FS-N&lt;</font></b>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">não</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[não]</font>  <font color="blue"><b>ADV</b> </font> <font color="darkgreen">@ADVL&gt;</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">amar</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[amar]</font>  &lt;vt&gt; <font color="blue"><b>V</b> FUT 1/3S SUBJ VFIN </font> <font color="darkgreen">@FMV</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">uma</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[um]</font>  &lt;arti&gt; <font color="blue"><b>DET</b> F S </font> <font color="darkgreen">@&gt;N</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">pessoa</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[pessoa]</font>  &lt;H&gt; <font color="blue"><b>N</b> F S </font> <font color="darkgreen">@&lt;ACC</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">tão</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[tão]</font>  &lt;dem&gt; &lt;quant&gt; <font color="blue"><b>ADV</b> </font> <font color="darkgreen">@&gt;A</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">linda</font></b> 

    <font color="maroon">[lindo]</font>  <font color="blue"><b>ADJ</b> F S </font> <font color="darkgreen">@N&lt;</font>
    <dt><b><font color="maroon">.</font></b> 

    </dl>
```

Comment: You need to reread preg_match's documentation (missing delimeter and escaping). Anyway, if you just want to check if a string (vs. pattern) is part of another string use `str(i)pos(...) !== false`

Comment: Thanks man!! strpos worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `]` and `[` in your regular expressions because these have their own meaning. Use `\` as escape character for this. Try something like:

```
$er = '/\['.$term.'\]/';
```

Also, you can ignore upper/lower case adding the `i` modifier after your delimiter:

```
$er = '/\['.$term.'\]/i';
```

Btw, when using double quotes for strings, you can use curly braces as substitute to concatenation. This is called variable interpolation:

```
$er = "/\[{$term}\]/i";
```